# IBKR API buy fractional stocks

Tags: c#, trading, interactive-brokers

I'm using Visual Studio to design a software that uses IBKR API to buy stocks. It's working fine if I'm buying integer stocks but I'm not able to buy fractional stocks.

I have found the function order.CashQty but it's not working.. this is the code that I'm using to buy, and it's working when I'm trying to buy integer stocks. Do you have any suggestion?

```
public void send_order(string side)
{
    IBApi.Contract contract = new IBApi.Contract();
    contract.Symbol = Global_variable.stock_sel;
    contract.SecType = "STK";
    contract.Exchange = cbMarket.Text;
    contract.PrimaryExch = "ISLAND";
    contract.Currency = "USD";

    IBApi.Order order = new IBApi.Order();
    order.OrderId = order_id;
    order.Action = side;
    order.OrderType = cbOrderType.Text;

    //order.CashQty = 33.5; <-- maybe is this the way to buy fractionale share?
    order.TotalQuantity = 1;

    if (cbOrderType.Text == "STP")
    {
        order.AuxPrice = Convert.ToDouble(numPrice.Value);
    }

    order.DisplaySize = Convert.ToInt32(tbVisible.Text);
    order.OutsideRth = chkOutside.Checked;
    ibClient.ClientSocket.placeOrder(order_id, contract, order);

    order_id++;
    tbValid_Id.Text = Convert.ToString(order_id);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: According to this [forum discussion](https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topic/69203949), it looks like IB isn't planning to allow fractional trading via the API.

Answer (score 0):

that code of my program, I hope that will help you:

```
private void buyStock(string symbol)
    {
        // Create a new contract to specify the security we are searching for
        IBApi.Contract contract = new IBApi.Contract();

        // Set the underlying stock symbol from the cbSymbol combobox
        contract.Symbol = symbol.ToUpper();
        // Set the Security type to STK for a Stock
        contract.SecType = "STK";
        // Use "SMART" as the general exchange
        contract.Exchange = "SMART";
        // Set the primary exchange (sometimes called Listing exchange)
        // Use either NYSE or ISLAND
        contract.PrimaryExch = "ISLAND";
        // Set the currency to USD
        contract.Currency = "USD";

        IBApi.Order order = new IBApi.Order();
        // gets the next order id from the text box
        order.OrderId = order_id;
        // gets the side of the order (BUY, or SELL)
        order.Action = "BUY";
        // gets order type from combobox market or limit order(MKT, or LMT)
        order.OrderType = "MKT";
        // number of shares from Quantity
        order.TotalQuantity = 400;
        // Value from limit price
        //order.LmtPrice = Convert.ToDouble(numPrice.Text);
        //

        //Visible shares to the market
        //  order.DisplaySize = Convert.ToInt32(tbVisible.Text);
        //order.OutsideRth = cbOutsideRTH.Checked;
        //order.OutsideRth = chkOutside.Checked;


        // Place the order
        ibClient.ClientSocket.placeOrder(order_id, contract, order);

        // increase the order id value
        order_id++;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any answer on the `order.CashQty` part of the question?  How does your code solve the problem ?